# data not written when writing to a CSV file while reading and doing operation on it

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write to a file while doing operations to the data read from another csv file, but the problem is the content is not being written out to the file. Here is my code snippet. Any help is greatly appreciated.
The csv file I am reading looks something like this.

CustID  CustName    PrincipleAmount NumberOfYears   DepositType FinalAmount

1   Aaa 100,000 2   Saving
2   Bbb 5,000   5   Fixed
3   Ccc 8,200   4   Saving
4   Ddd 15,000  10  Fixed
5   Eee 6,500   20  Fixed

```
    from os import path
    my_path = 'C:\\JupyterNotebook\\'
    with open(path.join(my_path, 'Deposit.csv'), 'r+') as open_file, open(path.join(my_path, 
    'Deposit2.csv'), 'w+') as write_file:
        table = open_file.read()
        #headers = next(rows,None)
        rows =  table.split('\n')
        headers = str(rows.pop(0))

        to_write  = headers 
        write_file.write(to_write)
        result =[]
        for row in rows:
            if(len(row) == 0):   
                continue
            content = list(filter(lambda x: x not in ("", " "), row.split(',')))
            principal, years, deposit_Type = float(content[2]), float(content[3]), content[4]
            Amount = final_Amount(principal, years, deposit_Type)
            to_write = "%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s" % (content[0], content[1], content[2], content[3], content[4], Amount)
            write_file.write(to_write)

        print(write_file.read())
```

Comment: Have you tried `write_file.seek(0)` (position pointer to start of file) before `print(write_file.read())`?

Comment: or reopen the write_file in another with block  for reading, to avoid any unexpected OS buffer.